# Relationship between set topologies

Tags: general-topology

> What relationship of contents exists between the topologies $(\mathbb{R}^{2}, \text{usual})$ and $(\mathbb{R}^{2}, \text{lexicographic})$?

This question appeared on a test and feeling uncertain, i replied that $(\mathbb{R}^{2}, \text{usual}) \subseteq (\mathbb{R}^{2}, \text{lexicographic})$, for every ball can be written as a union of horizontal intervals (i.e. is the union of open balls in $(\mathbb{R}^{2}, \text{lexicographic})$ intervals of the form $((a,b),(a,c))$ with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R^{2}}$), but not every fringe (open balls in $(\mathbb{R}^{2}, \text{lexicographic})$ of the form $((a,b),(c,d))$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R^{2}}$) can be written as a union of open balls in $(\mathbb{R}^{2}, \text{usual})$ because one can not grab the edge of the fringe with open balls of the usual topology.

Is this correct? Or is there no relationship between these sets, as could write more rigorously this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You’re right about the relationship, but your argument can be improved a little.

The open interval $\big(\langle a,b\rangle,\langle a,c\rangle\big)$ in the lexicographic order topology is vertical, not horizontal, but it’s certainly true that every Euclidean open set is a union of such intervals, and that the Euclidean topology is therefore a subset of the lexicographic order topology. The best way to show that it’s a proper subset is to exhibit a specific open set in the order topology that is not open in the usual topology. One such set is the interval $\big(\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 0,1\rangle\big)$ in the order topology, which does not contain any non-empty Euclidean open set and is therefore certainly not open in the Euclidean topology.